# Events from AJAX-Source are not added to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I get some data from an PHP-Script via AJAX and want to have the return value as an event listed in my fullcalendar. But somehow it didn't work! I copied the example from the fullcalendar documentation and modified it a little bit:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "content/con_FillDatesToPopulateEvent.php",
      data: { 
          start: startStr, 
          end: endStr,
      },
      success: function (returnVal) {
          var events = [];
          singleEvents = returnVal.split("|");
          $.each(singleEvents, function(i, val){
                events.push(val);
          });
      callback(events);   
      }               
});
```

If I display the return value of my PHP-Script the events are looking fine:

```
{ 
  id: 15, 
  title: '???', 
  start: '2012-06-11 11:00:00', 
  end: '2012-06-13 11:00:00', 
  url: '#', 
  allDay: false, 
  color: 'Orange' 
},
{ 
  id: 7, 
  title: '???', 
  start: '2012-05-28 08:00:00', 
  end: '2012-06-10 08:00:00', 
  allDay: false, 
  color: 'Orange' 
}, 
{ 
  id: 6, 
  title: '???', 
  start: '2012-05-21 08:00:00', 
  end: '2012-05-28 08:00:00', 
  allDay: false, 
  color: 'Orange' 
}
```

As far as I understand all events should be added to the fullcalendar by the call of "callback()"? Do you see my problem and can you give me a hint how to fix it? I'm searching for a while on the internet without an satisfying solution!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What does the callback() function do? Can you post the code of that function here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call .fullCalendar, you can pass in a parameter "events" which defines a JSON source for the events. Example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'content/con_FillDatesToPopulateEvent.php'
});
```

and that should be all you need to populate the events. Your code isn't clear on what `callback` is or does.